# Afrer return a BehaviorSubject , app was pulled for multiple result

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I want to use from BehaviorSubject for my login user.
i have `user` BehaviorSubject. that retuen a abservble.

```
 get IsAuthenticated() {
return this.user.asObservable().pipe(switchMap(res => {
  if (res != null) {
    return of(true);
  }
  return of(false);
}));

}
```

for using this result abservble i use `take(1)` but return multiple one result and hangout app.

```
return this.authService.IsAuthenticated.pipe(take(1),tap(res => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res == true) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/status");
      }else{
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/auth");
      }
    }));
```

[image]

Comment: Do you fire this code from the `status` and `auth components?  If so, it will just keep redirecting you infinitely.

Comment: thank you @BizzyBob. i remove redirection to /status and problem solved. thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your second code block is in a route guard, and that route guard is falsely configured in at `path: "auth"`. Remove it from `canActivate`.